# Using xcassets datasets with .xml files, images, folders etc. for separate targets

Tags: ios, xcode

I am curently converting my app source from an entirely different tool to Swift tarrgeting ios7 and newer. I now have an xcode project setup for multiple targets (some source, multiple apps) where each app has its own ".xcassets* file like this:

- customerapp1_AppIcon
- customerapp1_LaunchImage

And then also:

- customerapp1_DataSet (.xml data files and some images)
- customerapp1_DataSet_Folder1 (images)
- customerapp1_DataSet_Folder2 (images)

The idea is hat the app at startup will use these files (if it finds newer ones online, it will download them to cache and use those instead)

However, researching this further, I now have some doubts:

1) Is this an incorrect use of xcassets if my goals is to have a way to include different files depending on target?

2) How do I load files found in **"customerapp1_Data_Folder1"** (and what if I e.g. have an image file with the same filename in two folders?)

3) If above is incorrect use - would a solution be to zip all my own data + image files + foldes into a single .zip file. Store that single file in **"customerapp1_Data"** and then unzip into cache directory at first startup? (That way, my own data structure would also be kept)

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing is to:

Select app project root in acode - build phaes - copy bundle resources

Add folder using "add folder references"

Select the appropriate target for the bundle files